# Getting the key for second maximum value from a dictionary, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, dictionary

I am doing it this way but if there is any easy/efficient way of doing it

```
def get_second_max(dic):
    count = 0
    ind =0
    vals = list(dic.values())
    for val in vals:
        count = 0
        for value in vals:
            if value > val:
                count += 1
            if count > 2:
                break
        if count == 1:
            ind = vals.index(val)
    return list(dic.keys())[ind]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the dict keys by their value and get the second to last item:

```
sorted(dic, key=dic.get)[-2]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to return the values in the dictionary (test it with `dic={1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'a'}`)

Comment: The question was for the KEY. Test with `dic =  { 'a':7, 'b':1, 'c': 8', 'd': 3 }` to get `a` which has value `7`, second highest.

Comment: Oh, second **maximum**! I don't know why I read second most common value there.